# What is the easy way to debug or find some typo in your code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was doing practicing node.js and express.js.

I had this issue of finding some typos. I typed

```
const decoded = jwt.veryfy(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
```

instead of `jwt.verify`

I found what I typed wrong, however, I was wondering how I could notice if there are some typos.
VScode or any console didn't tell me any errors, that's why I took some time to find the typo.

Could you give me some advice dealing with sort of this issues? I mean, How could you know you typed wrong even if no error is displayed? Any thoughts?

Comment: Read about TypeScript.  If you have proper logging of errors, this line of code should have generated an immediate error and stack trace the moment it ran and it should have been trivial to see the error then and identify it.  If you weren't getting good info when the error was occurring, that's probably because your error handling or logging was lacking.  But, since Javascript is not a compiled language and is not a type language, there is no error until you try to execute the line of code.  That's why some people use TypeScript which is "compiled" into Javascript and includes type checking.

Comment: This issue is about finding errors for code shown in the the editor, not at runtime. Also you don't need to use TypeScript to get errors to show in VS Code's editor. Suggesting switching languages is not an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, VS Code's JS intellisense only checks syntax. However If you [enable type/semantic checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking) it will also validate the contents of your program, including producing errors for misspelled/unknown property names

To test type checking, just add `// @ts-check` at the top of your JS file

Comment: Thanks for your input, Matt. It solved the issue in some way. @ts-check is not catching every typos, but it helps find some!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's impossible to know what was happening in the surrounding environment, i.e. was this in a try/catch that swallowed the error. When invoking a function that doesn't exist as a property of an object, Node will throw `TypeError: foo.bar is not a function`, with the method and object name being relevant to whatever you're trying to access.

To answer your question, however, there are plugins for spellchecking and VS Code by default will attempt to provide you with a list of auto-complete method and property names of a defined object, like so: [image: screenshot of VS Code auto-complete]

Comment: Yeah Vscode gives me autocompletion of jwt.verify like you said. But I typed jwt.veryfy instead of jwt.verify for some reason. And then, I had no idea what I did wrong.